# Neo4j Movie Database centrality

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

H, i'm fairly new to neo4j and cypher in general and i just started playing around with the default movie database provided on neo4j's installation.

I'm trying to obtain a measure that reflects the importance of each movie based on the actors that acted in them that in some iterative way would take into account the importance of each actor based on the number of movies they acted in.

I guess my best option here would be to use pageRank score:

```
CALL algo.pageRank(label, relationship, ...)
```

What would be in this situation the best and most correct way to obtain what i'm looking for?

I'm quite lost and googling around didn't help as much as i hoped. Thanks for reading, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: PageRank is the best place to start. How do you define the *"importance of each movie"*?

Comment: @A_A I guess you could say that a movie is important if the actors that acted in it have acted in many different movies. Does it make sense? So if actor A1 has acted in 10 movies one of which is movie M1 and actor A2 has acted in 3 movies one of which is movie M2 then, provided that A1 is the only actor in M1 and A2 is the only actor in M2, then M1 is more important than M2. I really hope it makes sense

Comment: That waiting is very close to PageRank. Why not implement that directly (?), since you seem to have a good grasp of the sort of quantity you are after.

Comment: @A_A you mean make my own algorithm instead of using neo4j's library? I'm not sure how to do that, i was hoping there was some kind of MATCH query i could feed to the relationship value in algo.pageRank(), something like algo.pageRank('Movie', 'MATCH ... ', ...), but i have no idea how to do that